# flutterfire configure --project=whatsappclone-64bbf doesn't generate a lib/firebase_options.dart file in my case

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cli

I was connecting my WhatsApp clone using flutter project to firebase. I successfully installed the firebase CLI but i am facing issues while configuring the project. The command flutterfire configure should ideally generate a file named firebase_options.dart file in lib folder but in my case this doesn't seem to happen :(

Answer (score 0):

> Install Firebase CLI  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli
> run the below commands in your flutter project

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

> 

```
flutterfire configure
```

After you run these commands, the firebase_options.dart file will be generated in **lib/ folder.**

add the following lines of code in your main.dart file
make sure to add  `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` above all

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```